# JQuery TimeCircles - display minutes and seconds in one circle

Tags: timer, countdown

I'm using the Jquery TimeCircles plug in (https://github.com/wimbarelds/TimeCircles) as a timer on my application, but I would like to have it so that there is only one circle with the minutes and seconds in the middle, like 15:40. I would like the seconds to keep ticking down, but the circle should animate according to the minutes only. Currently I have two circles showing the minutes and seconds.

I would like to start the timer at 50 minutes, and then countdown to 0 minutes and 0 seconds. Is there any way I can have the time display in the format MM:SS inside the one circle, and have the number of seconds ticking down, and the circle animating to the number of minutes ticking down only?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually had a fairly similar request the other day on github:
https://github.com/wimbarelds/TimeCircles/issues/68

You could change it to something like:

```
var $container = $('#DateCountdown .textDiv_Minutes');
$container.find('h4').text('Time left');
var $original = $container.find('span');
var $clone = $original.clone().appendTo($container);
$original.hide();

$('#DateCountdown').TimeCircles().addListener(function(unit, value, total) {
    total = Math.abs(total);
    var minutes = Math.floor(total / 60) % 60;
    var seconds = total % 60;
    if(seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;
    $clone.text(minutes + ':' + seconds);
}, "all");
```

You'd need to use the TimeCircles options that make it only display the Minutes circle.

Comment: Thank you so much Wim! this mostly works except for one small thing. 

'You'd need to use the TimeCircles options that make it only display the Minutes circle.'

However, when I hide the seconds option like this:

"Minutes": {
              "text": "Minutes",
              "color": "#99CCFF",
              "show": true
          },
          "Seconds": {
              "text": "Seconds",
              "color": "#99CCFF",
              "show": false
          }
the seconds that are ticking down in the minutes circle stop, so the seconds wont tick down anymore. How can I fix this? Thanks so much!

Comment: Ah, forgot :) .addListener() has two parameters, one of which is optional. We need to add "all" as second parameter. I'll edit the post / code to something that should work as you want.